# How to populate dropdown with api data in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to populate the options of a dropdown with all the titles from [this](https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films) API.

I'm trying to:

- Save the titles into the titles : [] object
- Map all those titles into separate  elements

But I'm getting the error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot convert undefined or null to
> object

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
    import React from "react"
import Header from "./Header"
import CardContent from "./CardContent"
import axios from "axios";

class CardContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    display: [],
    titles: []
  };

  componentWillMount = (e) => {
    axios.get("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")
      .then(response => this.setState({
        titles: response.data[Object.keys(response.data.title)],
        display: response.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.data.length)]
      }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <select>
          {this.state.titles.map(title => (
            <option key={title} value={title}>
              {title}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use `componentDidMount` to do the data fetch, but the main issue is that you appear to want an array of all the titles, so you need to map over the response data and create this array.

```
componentDidMount = (e) => {
  axios.get("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films").then((response) =>
    this.setState({
      titles: response.data.map(({ title }) => title), // <-- map titles
      display: response.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.data.length)]
    })
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-populate-dropdown-with-api-data-in-react]

Comment: Currently, this.state.display is pulling a random title, description, etc and displaying them onto the page in tables etc. There's a button which does handleChange() and reupdates this.state.display to a random movie. I plan to setup another event listener on the select dropdown to update this.state.display to the selected movie.

Comment: @esvnt Ah, kk. As I said, was just guessing from the snippet. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error as "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot convert undefined or null to object"  because response.data is an array. Object.key() can be only applied to objects. Try map() function to extract the objects one by one.